# Angular Universal 5 - Meta Service not working

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I had my meta tags working for Facebook and Twitter but I've somehow broken them. I looked at examples, but I can't see the issue. (There are no errors.) The tags just don't change from the defaults in index.html. I'm using Angular Universal 5.

Unlike the examples I found, I'm not writing the tags in the constructor. Not sure if that's a factor. I must be missing some rule of using the Meta service. Here's the code...

```
    import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    ...

    constructor( ... private metaService: Meta ... ) {}

    ngOnInit () { 
    ...  

        // <!-- Facebook meta data -->
        this.metaService.addTags([
         {property: 'og:title', content: 'test' },
         {property: 'og:url', content: 'url' },
        ]);
        // <!-- Twitter meta data -->
        this.metaService.addTag({name: 'twitter:title', content: 'test });
   ...
   }
```

Comment: It does not need to be in the constructor. What if you try with updateTag instead of addTag?

Comment: @David thx! updateTag works. I'm shaking my... I must have broken it by changing the default (static) tags in index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tags are already there, you need to use `updateTag` instead of `addTag`

Looking at the source code, `addTag` does not add the meta tag if it's already present in the dom (like in index.html)

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/browser/meta.ts

**Note** `updateTag` does add the meta to the dom if it does not already exists

Answer (score 0):

As @David suggested, switching from `addTag` (and `addTags`) to updateTag fixed the issue.