# Angular server side rendering - Meta tags are not rendering

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have used server-side rendering in Angular to make my site SEO friendly.

So, I have added meta tags dynamically based on the data I receive in the API.

The issue is, the meta tags are not shown when I see **view page source** from the browser. But when I keep meta tags static then it gets display on **view page source**. Below is my code.

> **Code:**

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';       

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAll()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.meta.addTag({ name: 'description', content: res.aboutUs }, true);
      this.meta.addTag({ name: 'keyword', content: res.keywords }, true);
      this.meta.addTag({ name: 'title', content: `${res.storeName} Shop` }, true);    
      this.meta.addTag({ name: 'google-site-verification', content: res.googleCode }, true);
    }, error => {
         // handle error here..
    });
  }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.
    get(`https://api.com/someapi`).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: See here if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644839/1160794